# Android: appropriate usage of the options menu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I've seen a fair number of applications which use the options menu to access functions like adding items, viewing settings, etc. Then there are others where the "adding items" function (and other key functions) are moved to buttons elsewhere on the screen.

I was wondering: is the use of buttons to access key application functions (e.g. adding items) better/more efficient than accessing said functions through an options menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally speaking I use option menu in the situation where I need maximum space on the screen like for example free hand drawing making options like erase,pensize,color,etc would occupy alot of space on the screen.

but to me the best practice is to place the options that are not that frequently used in option menu . and ones that are used regularly shall be on screen.